# div does not expand with content inside it..?

Tags: html, size

HELP!?? I am creating a site, and for some reason, the main div that houses all the content does not seem to automatically expand when content is inside it.

code is below.

THANKYOU!

html:

```
<!-- Content -->
<div class="content-wrapper clearfix">
  <div id="content">
  {% if template == 'list-collections' %}
    {% include 'collection-listing' %}
  {% else %}
    {{ content_for_layout }}
  {% endif %}

  {% unless template contains "customer" or template contains "cart" %}
    {% include 'col-widgets' %}
  {% endunless %}
  </div>
</div>
</div><!-- /.content -->
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
  width: 810px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: left;
  min-height:100%;
  }
.ie6 .wrapper{ height: 100%; } 

      #content {
      height:200px;
      width: 810px;
      background-color:#fff;
      position: absolute;
      } 

#col-main{
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top:0px;
  line-height: 2;
    margin: 5px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: center;
  position: relative; z-index: 1;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #D5DCE1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `height:auto;` to `#col-main` should fix it.

Comment: THANKYOU!! any idea why there is also a huge yellow space underneath? (last question I promise!)

Comment: try `height:auto;` under `#content` as well.  That may fix it.